# Protractor/Javascript - Reference syntax to pass function into a value for expect clause

Tags: javascript, protractor, pageobjects

Newbie to protractor and Javascript so go easy on me.  Can anyone tell me the syntax for an extra line to call the following page object in a function (within my test spec) before I use my expect clause?

Method/Function in Page Object:

```
this.getHeaderText = function(){
  element.all(by.css('.ag-header-cell-text'))
    .map(function(header){
        return header.getText()
    }).then(function(headers){
    if (headers.toEqual(['Publisher Name', 'IpAddress', 'AddedDate', 'Delete Ip']));
    return 1;
  });
};
```

Call in test spec for expect:

```
it('All headers are present', function(){
// Need syntax here for reference to pass PO function into a value to call below
   expect(publisher_whitelist_page.getHeaderText.getText().toEqual(1));
 });
});
```

As a result I am getting the following error
 - Failed: publisher_whitelist_page.getHeaderText.getText is not a function

Once again, any help or advice is greatly appreciated and welcomed!

Thanks!

Kirsty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code with below snippet.

**pageObject.js file:**

```
this.getHeaderText = function(){
    return element.all(by.css('.ag-header-cell-text')).getText();
}
```

**spec.js file:**

```
it('All headers are present', function(){
   expect(publisher_whitelist_page.getHeaderText()).toEqual(['Publisher Name', 'IpAddress', 'AddedDate', 'Delete Ip']);
});
```

Comment: Modified as above, still getting the error: × All headers are present
        - Failed: Cannot read property 'toEqual' of undefined

Comment: My bad! I forgot to add return statement inside `getHeaderText()` method. I have updated my answer, try it once again!

Answer (score 0):

Your page object function have some issues.

```
this.getHeaderText = function(){
  return element.all(by.css('.ag-header-cell-text'))
    .map(function(header){
        return header.getText()
    }).then(function(headers){
    if (headers.toEqual(['Publisher Name', 'IpAddress', 'AddedDate', 'Delete Ip']));
    return 1;
  });
};
```

You dont have to call .getText() again.

Try like this.

```
expect(publisher_whitelist_page.getHeaderText()).toEqual(1);
```

Let me know if you have not got yet.

first use console.log to check what is the value of headers in page object.like this
**EDIT**

```
this.getHeaderText = function(){
  return element.all(by.css('.ag-header-cell-text'))
    .map(function(header){
        return header.getText()
    }).then(function(headers){
    console.log('data', headers, typeof headers);
  });
};
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
this.getHeaderText = function(){
      return element.all(by.css('.ag-header-cell-text'))
        .map(function(header){
            return header.getText()
        }).then(function(headers){
        if(JSON.stringify(headers)==['Publisher Name', 'IpAddress', 'AddedDate', 'Delete Ip'])
return 1;
      });
    };
```

comment me what you are getting

Comment: Nope getting the below error when I use the above:  Element checks All headers are present
  - Expected undefined to equal 1.
  - Failed: headers.toEqual is not a function

Comment: Have you included the page object file properly in your spec file. For example: by using require

Comment: yes I have at the top of the test spec file:  var login_page = require('../Pages/login_page.js');

Comment: Tried again with edited answer and still getting:  Element checks All headers are present
  - Failed: headers.toEqual is not a function

Comment: tell what you are getting at console. like I have told you above in my answer..After EDIT Heading

Comment: data [ 'Publisher Name', 'IpAddress', 'AddedDate', 'Delete Ip' ] object
      × All headers are present
        - Expected undefined to equal 1.

Comment: Thats right.. You can not use toEqual function here like this. I have updated the Answer. Try that and ping me..

Comment: changed and tried with Update 2 answer as above but still getting: × All headers are present
        - Expected undefined to equal 1.

Comment: Got it working as above with first answer but thanks for all your help Vikash.777 I really appreciate it! :D